# Lazy Loading Performance Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, limit, loading, lazy-evaluation

We have a table which is displaying some Results. Due to some Thirdparty Database Layout, the Query to fetch the results is made out of upto 15 `Left Joins`.

Currently the result count is at about 5000, Which takes about 1.0 Second to fetch.

So, instead of fetching ALL results, we added Lazy Loading, using Mysqls `Limit` and a pagination on the table.

The ListQuery is now down to about 0.0x seconds, when fetching about 50 rows.

However, for the "Paginator" of the table, we need the total count of elements. And this count query currently takes 1 second. So we are not really getting anything out of the change...

The problem is, that the count Query ofc. needs to contain the same joins, same where-conditions as  a regular query (sorting ignored ofc.) - but **no limit**...

The problem is, that we cannot ommit the joins. EVERY join involved may reduce the result count due to search-tags beeing applied. (Every joined column needs to be present in the where-clause)

i.e. if the query would be made out of `3` columns (one per join), and the search is `one test`, the following condition needs to be added:

```
WHERE 
   (t1.column LIKE '%one%' OR t2.column LiKE '%one%' OR t3.column LiKE '%one%')
   AND
   (t1.column LIKE '%test%' OR t2.column LiKE '%test%' OR t3.column LiKE '%test%')
```

And so on. 3 Tags (`one more test`) would produce:

```
WHERE 
   (t1.column LIKE '%one%' OR t2.column LiKE '%one%' OR t3.column LiKE '%one%')
   AND
   (t1.column LIKE '%more%' OR t2.column LiKE '%more%' OR t3.column LiKE '%more%')
   AND
   (t1.column LIKE '%test%' OR t2.column LiKE '%test%' OR t3.column LiKE '%test%')
```

Any ideas, how we can "quickly" fetch the total result count in order to display the paginator? Already thought about loading the paginator and the total count asynchronoues - but maybe we are just missing the point on some important "fact"...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in combination with [FOUND_ROWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) to get the count of all rows without LIMIT clause:

> FOUND_ROWS()
>
> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT clause to restrict the number
>   of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is
>   desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned
>   without the LIMIT, but without running the statement again. To obtain
>   this row count, include a SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT
>   statement, and then invoke FOUND_ROWS() afterward:
>
> mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
>       -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10; mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
>
> The second SELECT returns a number indicating how many rows the first SELECT
>   would have returned had it been written without the LIMIT clause.

Comment: I didn't know this command by now. It is working, *but* - Now the list-query that contains `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and a limit is taking "1.0" second. Instead of finishing in 0.01. So it seems like mysql is internally doing quite the same (Additional Count query) as we do manually at the moment. Removing